# my Health points is not set to proper value when I build on android mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this project a 2D side scroller game, I have set my HP indicator as a slider inside my canvas which is screen space overlay the UI scale mode is "Scale with Screen size". Now when ever Im testing the game in unity the HP values is done right with correct default value of 20. But whenever I build my project unto my mobile phone my HP value is always set to zero. How can I fix my HP value whenever I build it unto my mobile phone.

This testing on Unity - The HP value "greed" green slider is set to the right value.

[image]

This is testing on mobile phone - the value turns to zero

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour {



//HUD Variables
public Slider healthSlider;

void Start () {

    bulan_fullhp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Bulan_hp");
    currHP = bulan_fullhp;
    Debug.Log ("Bulan HP is : " + currHP);

    healthSlider.maxValue = bulan_fullhp;
    healthSlider.value = bulan_fullhp;


}
```

The default value of HP is 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to you have not set it's value at first,

PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Bulan_hp");

If no value is set for "Bulan_hp" key then it will default returns 0.
So make sure to check if the key exists by following code.
And if key not found then assign it.

```
if !(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Bulan_hp"))
{
    // You can set this value to playerprefs
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Bulan_hp", 20);
}

// Then call get value
bulan_fullhp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Bulan_hp");
```

Or you can assign default value by this..

```
bulan_fullhp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Bulan_hp", 20);
```

So it won't be 0 for the first time.

Comment: I am glad it helped. 
And it's ma'm, not sir :D